# How to convert from GL_RGB to AVFrame

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg

For my project I need to convert a RGB (`GL_RGB`) Image generated by `glReadPixels` into a `AVFrame`. I've googled it and found just examples of the other way around. But in this case I need from `GL_RGB` to `AVFrame`.

Here's my code:

Here's how I set my codec:

```
/* Allocate resources and write header data to the output file. */
void ffmpeg_encoder_start(AVCodecID codec_id, int fps, int width, int height) {
    const AVCodec *codec;
    int ret;
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!codec ) {
        std::cerr << "Codec not found" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        std::cerr << "Could not allocate video codec context" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    c->width = width;
    c->height = height;
    c->time_base.num = 1;
    c->time_base.den = fps;
    c->keyint_min = 600;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open codec" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        std::cerr << "Could not allocate video frame" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;
    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Could not allocate raw picture buffer" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Fetching the pixels and setting the new frame:

```
BYTE* pixels = new BYTE[3 * DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.width * DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.height];

glReadPixels(0, 0, DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.width, DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
screenSrc->setNextFrame(pixels, DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.width, DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.height);
```

And the function that I have for the conversion:

```
static void ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(uint8_t *rgb) {
    const int in_linesize[1] = { 3 * c->width };
    sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_context,
            c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
            c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
            0, 0, 0, 0);
    sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *)&rgb, in_linesize, 0,
            c->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
}
```

All the code can be found [here](https://github.com/benny1611/OpenTextProjector)
[Here](https://github.com/benny1611/OpenTextProjector/blob/master/ScreenSource.cpp#L58) is the line that results in segmentation fault.

Unfortunately, the function gives me a segmentation fault. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`, before `glReadPixels`.

Comment: That didn't do the trick :(

Comment: The two last arguments of [sws_scale()](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__libsws.html#gae531c9754c9205d90ad6800015046d74) are arrays/pointers, have you checked for type issues (compiler warnings)? Where exactly does the segmentation fault happen?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I have some compiler warnings, but none of them says anything about the ```sws_scale()``` call. The segmentation fault occurs when I'm calling the ```sws_scale()``` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `sws_scale` is an array of pointers: `const uint8_t *const srcSlice[]`

Instead of pointer cast: `(const uint8_t * const *)&rgb`, place `rgb` pointer inside an array of pointers:

```
const uint8_t* const src_data[] = { rgb };

sws_scale(sws_context, src_data, in_linesize, 0,
            c->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
```

---

Example for converting RGB to YUV420P:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern "C"
{
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}


int main()
{
    //Use FFmpeg for building raw RGB image (used as input).
    //ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -frames 1 -f rawvideo rgb_image.bin
    
    const int width = 192;
    const int height = 108;
    unsigned char* rgb_in = new uint8_t[width * height * 3];

    const enum AVPixelFormat out_pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    //Read input image for binary file (for testing)
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FILE* f = fopen("rgb_image.bin", "rb"); //For using fopen in Visual Studio, define: _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS (or use fopen_s).
    fread(rgb_in, 1, width * height * 3, f);
    fclose(f);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

    //Allocate output buffers:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // YUV420p data is separated in three planes
    // 1. Y - intensity plane, resolution: width x height
    // 2. U - Color plane, resolution: width/2 x height/2
    // 3. V - Color plane, resolution: width/2 x height/2

    int out_linesize[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint8_t* out_planes[4] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };   

    int sts = av_image_alloc(out_planes,    //uint8_t * pointers[4], 
                             out_linesize,  //int linesizes[4], 
                             width,         //int w, 
                             height,        //int h, 
                             out_pix_fmt,   //enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, 
                             32);           //int align);   //Align to 32 bytes address may result faster execution time compared to 1 byte aligenment.

    if (sts < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: av_image_alloc response = %d\n", sts);
        return -1;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    
    
    //Get SWS context
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    struct SwsContext* sws_context = nullptr;

    sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_context,         //struct SwsContext *context,
                                       width,               //int srcW,
                                       height,              //int srcH,
                                       AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,    //enum AVPixelFormat srcFormat,
                                       width,               //int dstW,
                                       height,              //int dstH,
                                       out_pix_fmt,         //enum AVPixelFormat dstFormat,
                                       SWS_BILINEAR,        //int flags,
                                       nullptr,             //SwsFilter *srcFilter,
                                       nullptr,             //SwsFilter *dstFilter,
                                       nullptr);            //const double *param);

    if (sws_context == nullptr)
    {
        printf("Error: sws_getCachedContext returned nullptr\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Apply color conversion
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const int in_linesize[1] = { 3 * width }; // RGB stride
    const uint8_t* in_planes[1] = { rgb_in };

    int response = sws_scale(sws_context,   //struct SwsContext *c, 
                             in_planes,     //const uint8_t *const srcSlice[],
                             in_linesize,   //const int srcStride[], 
                             0,             //int srcSliceY, 
                             height,        //int srcSliceH,
                             out_planes,    //uint8_t *const dst[], 
                             out_linesize); //const int dstStride[]);


    if (response < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: sws_scale response = %d\n", response);
        return -1;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Write YUV420p output image to binary file (for testing)
    //You may execute FFmpeg after conversion for testing the output:
    //ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 192x108 -pixel_format yuv420p -i yuv420p_image.bin rgb.png
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    f = fopen("yuv420p_image.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(out_planes[0], 1, width * height, f);
    fwrite(out_planes[1], 1, width * height / 4, f);
    fwrite(out_planes[2], 1, width * height / 4, f);
    fclose(f);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Free allocated memory
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    av_freep(out_planes);
    sws_freeContext(sws_context);
    delete[] rgb_in;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and I still run into the same issue. I'll have a look into the problem, because I now suspect that it has something to do with the fact that more than one thread is using that RGB data. One is producing the data and another one is consuming it. So that may also be the cause of the segmentation faul.

Comment: I suggest you to start from something simple, test it, and gradually continue... I am sure this is a bug. In case you didn't test your code in small steps it is possible that you have many more issues.

Comment: After I've debugged the code and made 100% sure that the function is called when it should be called, I still get a segmentation fault when I call the ```sws_scale()``` function

Comment: Do you think it is related to the `GL_RGB`? What are the values of `c->height`, `frame->data`, `frame->linesize`? I don't think I can help you without a minimal reproducible (and executable) code sample...

Comment: I've updated the question with the initialization of my codec. My screen's resolution is 1080 X 1920 so ```c->height``` and ```c->width``` are set accordingly to these values

Comment: I can't see the problem just by reading the code. I added an example that converts RGB to YUV420. For executing the example, start by creating the input file using FFmpeg CLI: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -frames 1 -f rawvideo rgb_image.bin`. You may use the example as reference, or use it for creating a reproducible code sample.

Comment: I found the problem, after a while, I've noticed that I had a thread that was deleting the RGB data (I forgot ```delete``` command in that thread), so sometimes I had data and sometimes I didn't. It was my mistake all along and not computer's :) Thank you for your help/time!

Comment: Great! Seems line a difficult bug to find.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no apparent error in the posted code snippets, that could be verified like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

AVFrame *frame = nullptr;
AVCodecContext *c = nullptr;
SwsContext *sws_context = nullptr;

/* <copy_of_original_code> */
void ffmpeg_encoder_start(AVCodecID codec_id, int fps, int width, int height) { ... }
static void ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(uint8_t *rgb) { ... }
/* </copy_of_original_code> */

int main()
{
    const int width = 640, height = 480;
    uint8_t rgb_in[width * height * 3] = { 0 };
    ffmpeg_encoder_start(AV_CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, 1, width, height);
    ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(rgb_in);
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    /* TODO: deallocate all resources here */
    return 0;
}
```

And checked like this:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o prg prg.cpp -lswscale -lavcodec -lavutil
$ ./prg
OK
```

So, it is difficult to say where the issue originates. Possible questions that come to mind:

- Is the input buffer large enough? Are the used `DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.width` and `DEFAULT_MONITOR.maxResolution.height` values valid? Is it necessary to use the heap?
- Have the global `AVFrame`, `AVCodecContext`, `sws_context` pointer variables been initialized prior to their use?
- Does the segmentation fault happen all the time, when tested on multiple different machines? Or is it hardware/OS dependent? Are the [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) libraries up to date?
- Where is the exact point of failure in the used library in `sws_scale()`? (That could be checked by using a debug version and a debugger I guess, to see where the program crashes by drilling into that function...)
- What does [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) say?

The issue seems to be not directly related to [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/). FFmpeg's [libswscale library](https://ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html) documentation can be found [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/swscale_8h.html).

In order to find a better answer, it would help if the problem could be replicated by others with a similar [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I found the problem, after a while, I've noticed that I had a thread that was deleting the RGB data (I forgot ```delete``` command in that thread), so sometimes I had data and sometimes I didn't. It was my mistake all along and not computer's :) Thank you for your help/time!

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear that you've found the culprit :)